# Getting values from pointer to record type rtti field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti, delphi-xe3

I have run into trouble trying to access the pointer to a record type in my record data using Delphi's RTTI.

Please check the sample code that i have been working on.

```
  // Dummy Header
  typDummyHeader = ^tysDummyHeader;
  tysDummyHeader = record
    MessageCode : Integer;
    MessageLength : Integer;
  end;

  // Dummy record having header and trailer
  tysDummyRecord = record
    Header : tysDummyHeader;
    BotAmount : Double;
    SoldAmount : Double;
    SoldQty : Int64;
    BotQty : Int64;
    Tailer : typDummyHeader; // pointer to Dummy Header
  end;

  TclDummy = class
    class function GetFieldValue<T>(const pipInstance : Pointer;
                                const piclField : TRttiField) : string;

    class function ParseAndReturnString<T>(piclObject : T) : string;
  end;

  var
    frmRTTITest: TfrmRTTITest;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  procedure TfrmRTTITest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    losDummyRecord : tysDummyRecord;
  begin
    FillChar(losDummyRecord, SizeOf(tysDummyRecord), #0);
    losDummyRecord.Header.MessageCode := 5000;
    losDummyRecord.Header.MessageLength := 54433;
    losDummyRecord.BotAmount := 19.45;
    losDummyRecord.SoldAmount := 34.22;
    losDummyRecord.SoldQty := 102;
    losDummyRecord.BotQty := 334;
    losDummyRecord.Tailer := @losDummyRecord.Header;

    ShowMessage(TclDummy.ParseAndReturnString<tysDummyRecord>(losDummyRecord));
  end;

  class function TclDummy.GetFieldValue<T>(const pipInstance : Pointer;
                               const piclField : TRttiField) : string;
  begin
    case piclField.FieldType.TypeKind of
      tkFloat: Result := FloatToStr(piclField.GetValue(pipInstance).AsExtended);
      tkInt64: Result := IntToStr(piclField.GetValue(pipInstance).AsInt64);
      tkInteger: Result := IntToStr(piclField.GetValue(pipInstance).AsInteger);
      tkString: Result := Trim(piclField.GetValue(pipInstance).AsString);
    end;
  end;

  class function TclDummy.ParseAndReturnString<T>(piclObject : T) : string;
  var
    losContext : TRttiContext;
    losContextType : TRttiType;
    loclField : TRttiField;
    losRecordRTTI : TRttiRecordType;
    loclRecordField : TRttiField;
    losPointerType : TRttiPointerType;
    losValue : TValue;
  begin
    Result := EmptyStr;
    losContext := TRttiContext.Create;
    losContextType := losContext.GetType(TypeInfo(T));

    if losContextType.TypeKind = tkRecord then
    begin
      for loclField in losContextType.GetFields do
      begin
        case loclField.FieldType.TypeKind of
          tkRecord:
          begin
            losRecordRTTI := loclField.FieldType.AsRecord;
            for loclRecordField in losRecordRTTI.GetFields do
            begin
              Result := Result + '|' + GetFieldValue<T>(Addr(piclObject), loclRecordField);
            end;
          end; // tkRecord
          tkPointer:
          begin
            losPointerType := loclField.FieldType as TRttiPointerType;

            // Check only record type pointers.
            if losPointerType.ReferredType.TypeKind = tkRecord then
            begin
              losValue := loclField.GetValue(Addr(piclObject));
              if (not losValue.IsEmpty) then
              begin
                for loclRecordField in losPointerType.ReferredType.GetFields do
                begin
                  // Result := Result + '|' + ???????????
                end;
              end;
            end;
          end; // tkPointer
          else
            Result := Result + '|' + GetFieldValue<T>(Addr(piclObject), loclField);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    losContext.Free;
  end;
```

In the above sample, when the field is `tkPointer` which is pointing to a record type, how do I read the values from that ?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is to get a string concatenated with all the members inside the record, even if it contains nested records.

Comment: Isn't that what ParseAndReturnString already does? Call it recursively.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I need to get value from the pointer type. Please check for the comment with ?????????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Result := Result + '|' + GetFieldValue<T>(Addr(piclObject),loclRecordField);
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer of @bummi works but is not right.

It depends on usage.

If you use next code all works well:

```
var
  losDummyRecord : tysDummyRecord;
begin
  FillChar(losDummyRecord, SizeOf(tysDummyRecord), #0);
  losDummyRecord.Header.MessageCode := 5000;
  losDummyRecord.Header.MessageLength := 54433;
  losDummyRecord.BotAmount := 19.45;
  losDummyRecord.SoldAmount := 34.22;
  losDummyRecord.SoldQty := 102;
  losDummyRecord.BotQty := 334;
  losDummyRecord.Tailer := @losDummyRecord.Header;

  ShowMessage(TclDummy.ParseAndReturnString<tysDummyRecord>(losDummyRecord));
```

But if you use for example this code, parsing don't work correctly:

```
var
  losDummyRecord : tysDummyRecord;
  ExternalHeaderVar: tysDummyHeader;
begin
  ExternalHeaderVar.MessageCode := 23;
  ExternalHeaderVar.MessageLength := 25;

  FillChar(losDummyRecord, SizeOf(tysDummyRecord), #0);
  losDummyRecord.Header.MessageCode := 5000;
  losDummyRecord.Header.MessageLength := 54433;
  losDummyRecord.BotAmount := 19.45;
  losDummyRecord.SoldAmount := 34.22;
  losDummyRecord.SoldQty := 102;
  losDummyRecord.BotQty := 334;
  losDummyRecord.Tailer := @ExternalHeaderVar;

  ShowMessage(TclDummy.ParseAndReturnString<tysDummyRecord>(losDummyRecord));
```

Solutions is simple and works in both cases well and prevents unexpected errors in the future use:

```
      tkPointer:
      begin
        losPointerType := loclField.FieldType as TRttiPointerType;

        // Check only record type pointers.
        if losPointerType.ReferredType.TypeKind = tkRecord then
        begin
          losValue := loclField.GetValue(Addr(piclObject));
          if (not losValue.IsEmpty) then
          begin
            losValue.ExtractRawDataNoCopy(@NativeIntVar);
            for loclRecordField in losPointerType.ReferredType.GetFields do
            begin
              Result := Result + '|' + GetFieldValue<T>(Pointer(NativeIntVar),loclRecordField);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end; // tkPointer
```